# How do I print an input from the R shiny UI to the console?

Tags: r, shiny

**Situation**: I want to print an input variable from the R shiny UI to the console. Here is my code:

```
library(shiny)

ui=fluidPage(
  selectInput('selecter', "Choose ONE Item", choices = c("small","big"))
)

server=function(input,output,session){
  print("You have chosen:")
  print(input$selecter)
 }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Unfortunately I get this error message:

```
Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext() : 
  Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)
```

**Question**: What do I need to change my code to, in order to make it work?

Comment: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/debugging.html, look at `printf` tracing

Comment: The problem is not the `print` statement itself, it's the reference of `input$selecter` from outside of a reactive statement. It needs to be within a `observe`, `observeEvent`, (`reactive`, I think), or similar function.

Comment: Try `observeEvent(input$selecter, {cat("You have chosen:", input$selecter)})` in `server`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should use an `observeEvent` which will execute every time the input changes:

```
library("shiny")

ui <- fluidPage(
    selectInput('selecter', "Choose ONE Item", choices = c("small","big")),
    verbatimTextOutput("value")  
)

server <- function(input, output, session){

  observeEvent(input$selecter, {
    print(paste0("You have chosen: ", input$selecter))
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]