# How can I capture an iframe variable value from Shiny server?

Tags: javascript, r, iframe, shiny, shinydashboard

I intend to make a Javascript variable from an iframe available to be readable in Shiny. Following these answers:

-[Display HTML file in Shiny App](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69131937/7092954)

-[How do I print an input from the R shiny UI to the console?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48285828/7092954)

I was able to make the following code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = 'demo'),
    dashboardSidebar(
      sidebarMenu(
        menuItem('Banco de Dados',
                  tabName = 'banco_de_dados',
                  icon = icon('th'))
      )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = 'banco_de_dados',
        h2('Banco de Dados'),
        textOutput('view'),
        htmlOutput('map')
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$map <- shiny::renderUI({
    tags$iframe(seamless = 'seamless',
                src = 'foo.html',
                width = 800,
                height = 800)
  })

  clickCounter <- reactive({ input$clickCounter })

  output$view <- renderText(paste0('Click counter is: ', clickCounter()))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

And the `foo.html` in my `www` folder:

```html
<html>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    let clickCounter = 0;
  </script>
  <body>
    TEST
    <button id="myButton" onclick="clickCounter += 1;console.log(clickCounter);">Click here</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

The big problem right now is that I cannot capture `input$sclickCounter` value. And as you can see, I can change the variable value in the iframe and display it in my browser's console:

[image]

How can I fix this and make my code behave as I expect?

Comment: Is using `includeHTML` an option for you?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you are using the `iframe` for the sole purpose of displaying the html in your shiny app.

If we use `includeHTML` instead we can use the JS function `Shiny.setInputValue` to populate the input on the server side:

**app.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = 'demo'),
    dashboardSidebar(
      sidebarMenu(
        menuItem('Banco de Dados',
                  tabName = 'banco_de_dados',
                  icon = icon('th'))
      )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = 'banco_de_dados',
        h2('Banco de Dados'),
        textOutput('view'),
        htmlOutput('map')
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$map <- shiny::renderUI({
    includeHTML('www/foo.html')
  })
  clickCounter <- reactive({ input$clickCounter })
  output$view <- renderText(paste0('Click counter is: ', clickCounter()))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**www/foo.html**

```
<html>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    let clickCounterVar = 0;
    Shiny.setInputValue(id = 'clickCounter', value = clickCounterVar);
  </script>
  <body>
    TEST
    <button id = "myButton" onclick = "clickCounterVar += 1; Shiny.setInputValue(id = 'clickCounter', value = clickCounterVar);">Click here</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Please see [this](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/communicating-with-js.html) related article.